# Userscript metadata eaten by Chrome

Tags: javascript, userscripts

Chrome seems to be eating up my userscript metadata:

```
 // ==UserScript== 
 // @name Flag Offtopic button 
 // @version 1.0 
 // @description Vote-to-off-topic button
 // @author Manish Goregaokar (http://stackapps.com/users/10098/manishearth)
 // @license GNU GPL v3 (http://gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html) 
 // @include http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/* 
 // ==/UserScript==

function with_jquery(f) {
     var script = document.createElement("script");
     script.type = "text/javascript";
     script.textContent = "(" + f.toString() + ")(jQuery)";
     document.body.appendChild(script);
};

//(rest of script availible on request)
```

The script works, but the metadata doesn't (it tries to run on every site, the filename shows up instead of "Flag Offtopic button", etc)

I'm new to userscripts, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Something stupid, no doubt.

Additional info: initially, the script had an incompatible charset (dunno why). I changed it to UTF-8 using Dreamweaver's Modify>Page properties , and the script worked (with metadata). It later broke(can't remember when) the metadata, but I thought it was some errant space. Now I can't find what's wrong. The above code itself (when copy-pasted to notepad, saved as `abc.user.js`, and drag-dropped to Chrome) loses its metadata.

Comment: Which Chrome version are you using?

Comment: @RobW: Both Canary and Beta. Once I realized that the metadata broke, I kept switching to test (I mainly was testing it in Canary). It doesn't work in either, so it's not the fault of a millisecond update :/ Does it work for you?

Comment: I have created and imported the script with `with_jquery(function(){alert(0)});`, which worked as intended. Chrome 18.0.1025.142 Dev for Linux. Can you show your exact Chrome version (`chrome://version`)?

Comment: 20.0.1093.0 (Official Build 131102) canary AND 18.0.1025.151 (Official Build 130497) beta-m . The script works, just the metadata doesn't. It does its work on ALL SE sites, instead of MSO only by adding a small link. And when I drag drop it, instead of asking "Add Flag Offtopic Button?", it asks "Add FlaggOffTopic.js?". Other scripts work fine.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your script, not with the meta block. My demo only ran code on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/.

Comment: @RobW: Fixed it, see below. Some strange encoding artefact I guess. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was no doubt a UTF-8 BOM hiding in the front of the document.  That issue bit me the other day.

(Why the UTF-8 BOM even exists is certainly a good question, but why editors even use them is truly confusing.)

Answer (score 1):

Saving scripts with the encoding set to "Unicode (UTF-8)" (at least on a Mac using BBEdit) triggers the OP's problem.

Saving scripts as "Western (ISO Latin 1)" fixes it.

(For the sake of completeness: Google Chrome 19.0.1084.56, though I don't think that's relevant.)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Probably was an artifact of the encoding change--some hidden character.

I copied just the code to a new file (previously I'd been copying the whole shebang), copied headers from a working script, and modified them. It works.

Update: On a bit of investigation, the encoding change had managed to muddle up the first character. It didn't get parsed, by JS, so the script still worked, but Chrome/GM didn't like it.

FWIW:

```
// ==UserScript==
 // @name Flag Offtopic button
 // @version 1.0
 // @author Manish Goregaokar (http://stackapps.com/users/10098/manishearth)
 // @description Adds a self-navigating "Flag-offtopic" button to MSO
 // @license GNU GPL v3 (http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html) 
 // @include http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/*

 // ==/UserScript==
```